# IOS 8.0 Swift Request Location Permission requestAlwaysAuthorization is not prompting

Tags: ios, swift

I had a problem on IOS  Ask Request Permission for Location Usage in Always. IOS 8.0 Swift Request Location Permission `requestAlwaysAuthorization` is not prompting. I Add the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`
and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in info.plist. Then called the method   `locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()`. But No Prompting Happened. Need to know whats I done mistake

Comment: You might have already given permission, so it won't ask twice.

Comment: When first time app launch It should Ask know?

Comment: Anybody will help me regarding this issue?

Comment: Change bundle id and try run again, it should ask permission again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the permission added in your info.plist then i am suggesting you the following steps, Hope they May Help

1)Delete App from Device
2)Reset you privacy setting by

> Go to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy

If this not work then you should check again your keys in info.plist
You might want cross check with keys at doc from Here :https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Hope this may help you.
Good luck Ahead